# Issue on Programmatically get the EKEvent using eventIdentifier

Tags: ios, eventkit

The eventIdentifier getting on save is not able to fetch the event  using eventIdentifier.

So we are unable to update the EKEvent programmatically even if we have its eventIdentifier

In [SimpleEKDemo][1] provided by Apple

log the eventIdentifier on EKEventEditViewDelegate method

```
- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {

NSError *error = nil;

EKEvent *thisEvent = controller.event;

switch (action) {
case EKEventEditViewActionCanceled:
// Edit action canceled, do nothing.
break;

case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
// When user hit "Done" button, save the newly created event to the event store,
// and reload table view.
// If the new event is being added to the default calendar, then update its
// eventsList.
if (self.defaultCalendar ==  thisEvent.calendar) {

[self.eventsList addObject:thisEvent];
}

[controller.eventStore saveEvent:controller.event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&amp;error];
NSLog(@"thisEvent.id = %@", thisEvent.eventIdentifier);
[self.tableView reloadData];
break;

case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
// When deleting an event, remove the event from the event store,
// and reload table view.
// If deleting an event from the currenly default calendar, then update its
// eventsList.
if (self.defaultCalendar ==  thisEvent.calendar) {
[self.eventsList removeObject:thisEvent];
}
[controller.eventStore removeEvent:thisEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&amp;error];
[self.tableView reloadData];
break;

default:
break;
}
// Dismiss the modal view controller
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Run the application on device, we will get the eventIDentifier like :

eventidonsave = 3CB60848-6CCA-43BF-B2C6-9EB9F5CFBBB7:C6CDE9DAA864420BA9A2E02CD886369700000000000000000000000000000000

Get the event using event identifier on next run

```
EKEventStore *eventStore1 = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *event1  = [eventStore1 eventWithIdentifier: eventidonsave ];
if(event1){
      NSLog(@"event1 id = %@", event1.eventIdentifier);
}else{
      NSLog(@"Not Found");
}
```

### We will get "Not Found".

log the event ids in the place of fetching events, and run again the app

```
- (NSArray *)fetchEventsForToday {
    ....
    ....



    for(EKEvent *eachEvent in events){

        NSLog(@"eachEvent.id = %@", eachEvent.eventIdentifier);
    }
}
```

we can see we are getting a different eventIdentifier like 3CB60848-6CCA-43BF-B2C6-9EB9F5CFBBB7:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000646C6F747573C3010000000000000000100000000DA068F782418C4880257958003F776C

this is not the same as 'eventidonsave'

Hi all , thanks to reading. It got solved. The above code(not its edited) is working fine.
I guess the issue was, the eventid was logged before this line
"[controller.eventStore saveEvent:.. "

NO just moved to after save. and seems to be okay.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the EKEvent first and then fetch its identifier. It wil give u a null value till u dont save the Event.
`[self.eventStore saveEvent:event span: EKSpanFutureEvents error:&error];`